# Can someone explain dispatch_async() for me in this scenario

Tags: thread-safety, swift, dispatch

I had the following method in a separate class:

```
class API: NSObject {

    var data = NSData()
    var delegate: APIProtocol?

    func getItems(callback: (Array<Image>) -> ()) {
        let urlPath: NSString = "http://localhost:3000/files"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration() as NSURLSessionConfiguration
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config) as NSURLSession

        var dataTask = NSURLSessionDataTask()
        dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
            if (error == nil) {
                println("API at URL \(url)")

                let responseArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSArray
                var images = Image[]()
                for item: AnyObject in responseArray {
                    var location = Image(dict: item as NSDictionary)
                    images.append(location)
                }
                var img = images[0] as Image
                callback(images)

                //self.delegate?.didReceiveResponse(responseArray)
            }

        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

I couldn't get my `tableView` to reload when calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` inside the `callback()` until I added the `dispatch_async()` around it.

**My questions are:**

1) Why wouldn't it work without it and is it the proper thing for me to do now that it's refreshing the `tableView` correctly?

2) Is there another way to get it working without having to add the dispatch on the main queue?

```
api.getItems() { (theArray) in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.images = theArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        if (viaPullToRefresh) {
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote with absolutely no explanation? Whoever you are, you're an idiot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating a NSURLSession you can specify the delegate/completion queue. If you don't specify a queue

> the session creates a serial operation queue for performing all
>   delegate method calls and completion handler calls.

So this means that your callbacks are called on a private serial queue. Now, all UI must be updated on the main queue, this is why `tableView.reloadData()` wasn't working.

To remove the dispatch call to the main_queue create the session like this

```
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: nil, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
```

Comment: You, I like you. Thanks :)

Comment: @KevinBluer a/s/l?